# SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS didn't work in Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Trying to run Spark `Zeppelin` on `Yarn` cluster, I set the following variables in `zeppeline-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--executor-memory 512m --driver-memory 512m --executor-cores 2 --queue onlineQ"
```

But it didn't use the `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` values in deploying job on YARN! For example `executor-memory` is `1024m` as default. When I set `executor-memory` in the Zeppelin `interpreter` setting, it will be applied. As I should set `--queue` property for Spark Submit, is there any other way (than SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS variable) to set it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set in spark interpreter settings.

`spark.driver.memory` etc.

More information here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/interpreter/spark.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, with Zeppelin, the spark driver can be embedded in the Zeppelin interpreter java application.

So, all settings "spark.driver.*" will not work, because the java process is already running.

You can set zep interpreter java properties instead.